# Run a file:// from http://localhost/

Tags: javascript, html, hosting, filestream

I wonder to know how can I make my .html project run not from file:// but as a localhost because one of the functions I've implemented requires getUserMedia which browsers instantly block, when loading from file://. I've done a lot of research on this but I'm still not understanding how it should be done, so if you can, please explain it in detail if it's not too pretentious of me, of course.

Comment: You need some sort of http server - without knowing what OS you're running I wont recommend anything in particular

Comment: Install some IDE like NetBeans. Create Web project. add your html code to index html if its a single page application. Or the other way install server and run your project on that server

Comment: The most popular Webservers would be [nginx](http://nginx.org/) and [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)

Comment: @Jaromanda X, that's the goal to make it http://... and yeah, I'd prefer the second option - to create a.server and to make the folder with the project somehow hostable to my computer and it to run through this server... I've really a zero knowledge in server establishing,so far just javascript,.jquery, html and css, so don't wonder about my unawared comments, maybe... One guy told me that python can create localhost:/ but after I installed it it didn't work... Tx for the replays, so.far.

Comment: as I said, without knowing which OS you are running, it'd be presumptuous of me to recommend anything in particular

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I'm running Window 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Ubuntu (or any other similar Linux distro) run

```
apt-get install apache2
```

then move your files to the /var/www/html folder, and navigate to localhost in your browser.

On Windows, you can install [XAMPP](http://apachefriends.org), then move your files to wherever you installed it to in the `\htdocs` folder

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested and it worked!!! The all I did was to install XAMPP and after that to simply drag my files into htdocs. After that you've to simply go to browser and write localhost/your-project-name.html,  (html in my case...). Now the mic is working which is SUPER news. Thanks a lot for the help. I wished to rather make it work with node js as it doesn't need to move the project to another folder but... who cares, it works and it's great! Thank you! :)

Comment: If you want it to run under Node, you will need to install the [Node-Windows](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/x64/node-v0.12.7-x64.msi) package, then use their web server for your project specifically. I'm not a Node expert, just starting to learn it myself actually. But to my understanding, that's all you need to run a Node project on Windows

Answer (score 11):

install node js

```
npm install -g http-server
```

from the directory containing html files.

```
http-server ./ -p 80
```

reference https://github.com/indexzero/http-server

Comment: ok, I've installed node js and now what should I do with those two lines of code.instructions or whatever they are? I don't understand how to install this one ' npm install -g http-server  '  into my directory containing the project and the second one ' http-server ./ -p 80 ' I've no idea where to write, also.

Comment: @KDX2 you need to open a terminal or open the `nodejs command prompt` that was installed with nodejs. Then run the `npm` command which will install other node packages on you system. then you can run the `http-server` from the same command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

I use [**live-server**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) on my mac by running the below code on the command line from inside the folder containing your index.html:

```
live-server --port=8000
```

In addition to running index.html from localhost, live-server automatically reloads the page after any changes made to files that affect the dome for that page (i.e. .js or .css etc..) which can accelerate development.

**Installation**

You should probably install this globally.

```
npm install -g live-server
```

> note:
>
> - You need [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) in order to use npm.
> - --port= can be any free port and not nessessarly 8000.

Answer (score 1):

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

And you are good to go!

Start a server within seconds!

Note you do require an installed python

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3, then run this in the terminal:

```
python -m http.server
```

This should start a local host at port 8000. This can be configured within a python script that starts the server and then configures to the wanted settings.

Find more at the [HTTP servers Python 3.9 documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

*Edit*

This will start a local server for you where you can run .JS, .HTML, and .CSS