# await is only valid in async function when importing model Tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, python, keras, async-await, tensorflow.js

So currently I'm working on a web application that uses a model I built previously. I have the file stored locally in my github repository and I'm trying to retrieve that model and load it into a variable as so

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

<script>
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://foo.bar/tfjs_artifacts/model.json');
</script>
```

The first script tag should load in the tensorflow.js library (https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup).

The error that appears in the terminal is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Am I missing something with the tensorflow.js implementation? Or am I missing something with the await keyword in the model assignment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using the using the `await` keyword outside of an async function. [Async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) are special functions that allow the word await, which makes it so the program waits for the function to finish running.

A solution to this would be

```
async function tensorFlow(){
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://foo.bar/tfjs_artifacts/model.json');
}

tensorFlow()
```

or you can use the `.then()` function.

```
tf.loadLayersModel('https://foo.bar/tfjs_artifacts/model.json').then(model => {
     
};
```

Comment: So now my error is the following


```
platform_browser.js:28 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/firstName%20lastName/Your-Story/AI-Model/saved_model.pb. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: are you running on a localhost server or from a local file?

Comment: If you are not running on localhost, it may solve your problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332485/run-a-file-from-http-localhost) is a link to another stack overflow page that has instructions.

Comment: This is a local file from a repository

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
async function run(){
....
}

( async() =>{
  await run()
})()
```